How to use multiple fonts in NextJS
I'm having trouble loading multiple Google Web fonts in a NextJS application. I'm following the documentation here.
In my fonts.ts I define my fonts:
import { Inter, Heebo } from "next/font/google";

export const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], display: "swap" });
export const heebo = Heebo({ subsets: ['latin'], display: "swap" })

In my layout.ts I define Inter globally:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import { inter } from './fonts';


export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "NextJS Stack Overflow Test.",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

And I have two test headings in my page.tsx but the font is roboto for both:
import { heebo } from './fonts';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={`text-center ${heebo.className} white`}>Heebo</h1>
      <h2 className='text-center white'>Roboto</h2>
    </>
  );
}

Got a Github Repo here with a NextJS with the code above included:
https://github.com/Freddie-Pike/nextjs_font_stack_overflow
Also deployed the app to Vercel for easy testing:
https://nextjs-font-stack-overflow.vercel.app/
Does anybody know what's on the go?

Problem :

Can't apply multiple fonts in NextJS

Possible Cause :

Inter font passed in body


There's a solution by which you can pass font name in className without need of importing it (2nd approach given below).

Solution :
1. In your approach :
layout.ts :
Don't pass inter font to body, 1
<html lang="en" className={inter.className}>

page.tsx :
import { heebo } from './fonts';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
        <h1 className={`text-center ${heebo.className}`}>Heebo</h1>
        <h2 className={`text-center`}>Inter</h2>
    </>
  );
}


2. Using Tailwind CSS Variables to pass fonts :
1st approach is hectic because you have to import font multiple times throughout the project. To use multiple fonts you need to create variable, then pass that variable in tailwind.config.js & then use that in className.
#UPDATED 23 June 2024
Make these modifications to your code:
Remove fonts.ts & directly import fonts in layout.ts.
layout.ts :
import { Heebo, Inter } from "next/font/google";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], display: "swap", variable: '--font-Inter', });
const heebo = Heebo({ subsets: ['latin'], display: "swap", variable: '--font-Heebo', });

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={`${inter.variable} ${heebo.variable} font-Inter`}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}
// Default font is Inter (when you dont pass any specific font in className it will automatically set Inter)

tailwind.config.js :
theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            Inter: ['var(--font-Inter)'],
            Heebo: ['var(--font-Heebo)'],
        },
        ...
    },
},

To use the fonts :
// NO NEED TO IMPORT FONT FROM FILE

<h1 className='font-Heebo'>Heebo</h1>
<h2>Inter</h2>
// IS automatically Inter

Please Read :

Using Multiple Fonts : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#using-multiple-fonts
CSS Variables : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font#css-variables
Using Fonts in Next.js :

(Watch from 5:01 - 5:38) This approach is bit different, because they
make variable based on font family (Sans, Serif etc., rest everything is same as 2nd approach above.) https://youtu.be/L8_98i_bMMA?feature=shared&t=301
In my code, I have named them by their names, which keeps it clear what font are we using.

If this answer was solved your problem then mark it as solution. If this answer was very helpful then you may upvote. If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer as necessary)


Tried both solutions and neither worked for me unfortunately, unsure what I'm doing wrong. The classnames are being applied in the HTML so I know that much is working.

@Fredmental I checked your git branch tailwind_solution but there are no changes tailwind.config.js & other files.

@Fredmental I have updated the code, please try again.

Still no luck unfortunately. Pushed the code to the tailwind-solution-june-23rd-2024 branch.
